# Looking for IntelliJ Idea theme for someone red-green colorblind

Tags: intellij-idea, color-scheme, color-blindness

I'm colorblind and, while many themes for IntelliJ editors are just fine, I was wondering if there was a theme developed with the comfort of someone who is colorblind in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution would be to make your own color theme (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html) or pick one you like from the internet and edit it to best suit you.

And to answer best your question, there isn't, in my knowledge, a color theme for red-green colorblind BUT there are "soft" color themes, which simply use very little color.

EDIT: Forgot to say that there is also an option (in BETA) to adjust the IDE depending on your color deficiency (http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/09/intellij-idea-15-eap-help-us-test-the-adjustments-for-color-deficiency/), this may help.

Answer (score 8):

There is also an option in settings to turn on color-blind mode in settings

> Settings → Appearance & Behavior → Appearance → Adjust colors for red-green vision deficiency

[image]

You can find more details about changes it makes in [this document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v-eKjsN-nfeXhO9pUUy31TomOC9soAzaDoNrrRWJve8/edit).

UPDATE: As of 2018.3, IDEA has its own high contrast theme. It may be potentially useful in this case. You can access in in

> Settings → Appearance & Behavior

[image]

The example of the theme is here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, no theme seemed to fit my color-blind eye. So I spend some hours creating my own theme. It might not fit you, and it might be ugly, but it works for me :-)

https://github.com/oizo/intellij-colorblind-scheme

Comment: Interesting. As someone with (presumably) no color blindness, I find this quite hard to look at.

Comment: You most likely are very right in your statement, this definitely isn't designed with beauty in mind :-) 
I've been looking at a lot of some of the popular themes around the web, and though they might look nice, some of them are absolute nightmares for me to look at, they often use 'low contrast' colors or colors that, to me, are very similar next to each other. So i started out by using bits and pieces from 10-ish populare themes and started the painful process of tweaking all of it into a new theme. A theme that fits my very specific needs :-)

Comment: @oiZo Thanks for this, I think I'm going to use it in Android Studio, already code seems clearer to read. I assume you are red-green colourblind? Would you recommend using this with another specific overall IDE theme (not just the editor pane)?

Answer (score 0):

Settings → Appearance & Behavior → Appearance → Theme → **Windows 10 Light**

... solved the basic problem for me of not being able to read the word 'end' (too faded out) for example in:

```
print('zoo', end='')
```

What specifically is that called? And/or **what setting would control that word individually?** I want to change just that alone as I've grown to like IntelliJ's other choices.

*Allow me to take this opportunity to mention to you normies haha love ya that we red-green-not-so-fully-differentiated see color alright (it isn't "blindness"), if the Enchroma glasses give me the right idea I find it kind of overwhelming that your world is so awash in colors, like turning the saturation way up on a TV. For me it's just that pastels are extra dim-ish perhaps, in a manner of speaking, such an unexpected effect from red and green cones picking up some of each other's frequencies. Overlap.*